# Closed balls in $B(H)$ are totally bounded?!

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be  a separable Hilbert space. It is well-known that the strong operator topology is metrizable on bounded parts of $B(H)$.  The metric is given by:
$$d(x,y)=\sum \frac{\|(x-y)e_i\|}{2^i}$$
where $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis in $B(H)$.

Trivially the closed unit ball $B_1$ of $B(H)$ is $d$-bounded. Is  $B_1$ $d$-totally bounded too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the space $B(H)$ is infinite dimensional then the unit ball under the metric $d$ which is induced by the norm on $H$ is not compact.

But in a metric space a set is compact $\iff$ is complete and totally bounded with the subspace topology induced by the metric on that set.

So the unit ball $B_1$ is not totally bounded because it is not compact.

Comment: Could you please say why $B_1$ is $d$-complete?

Comment: @AliBagheri i did not say that it is complete..why just care if it is totally bounded or not

Comment: Of course $B_1$ is $d$-complete. The unit ball is sot-closed: a sot limit of contractions is a contraction. Even a wot limit of contractions is a contraction.